# Android can't get the correct database path

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get the path of my app's sqlite db file as I want to backup it to Google drive in app, but it gives me a different path:

```
String Path = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mydb.db").getAbsolutePath();
 File filePath = new File(Path);
```

This Path gives me: `/data/user/0/mypackage/databases/mydb.db`

But when I use:

```
 File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
 String Path ="/data/mypackage/databases/mydb.db";
File filePath = new File(data,Path);
```

So the final path is `/data/data/mypackage/databases/mydb.db` and with this path the backup is also working.

I can also see the db file there in the file browser in android studio when the device is attached.

So why the `getDatabasePath` gives me path like data/user/0/ ?

Comment: "So why the getDatabasePath gives me path like data/user/0/ ?" -- because it is a correct value. Each device user gets their own separate directory representing internal storage. `/data/data/` is a legacy value that gets mapped to the correct directory for the active user. Personally, I am wondering why `getDataDirectory()` returns the old value.

Comment: getDataDirectory() just returns "/data/", but now i tested it in production, and this path getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mydb.db").getAbsolutePath(); works fine, so it is then as you said, that in the file browser it is just mapped to data/data, but the real path can be obtained via mentioned way, not hardcoding it. Thank you for explaining